# Magnolia CMS: Search result item excerpt differs in quality between 5.4.1 and 5.4.3

Tags: search, jackrabbit, magnolia

**The quality of the item excerpt of a search result seems to differ between Magnolia 5.4.1 CE and 5.4.3 CE.** I have the same website/pages on both system. On 5.4.1, the excerpts look good and it actually shows the parts where the keywords occurs and highlights them, whereas on 5.4.3, the excerpts does not show this but instead shows weird UUIDs and author names, that should not be visible to a public user:

The content nodes on both systems have the identical content. I pretty much use the default installation of 5.4.1 and 5.4.3 CE.
Anybody else having this problem or knows a reason for this? Is it a bug? Any way to fix this without having to write my own SearchTemplatingFunctions or ExcerptProvider?

[image]

The code that I use for the search:

```
[#-------------- ASSIGNMENTS --------------]
[#assign queryStr = ctx.getParameter('q')!?html]

[#-------------- RENDERING --------------]
[#if queryStr?has_content]
    [#assign searchResults = searchfn.searchPages(queryStr, '/mysubfolder') /]
    [#assign recordsFound = searchResults?size /]

    <h3><em>${recordsFound}</em> ${i18n['search.pagesFoundFor']} "${queryStr}"</span></h3>

    <div class="list-group">
        [#if searchResults?has_content]
            [#list searchResults as item]
                <a href="${cmsfn.link(item)}" class="list-group-item">
                    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">${item.title!}</h4>
                    <p class="list-group-item-text">${item.excerpt!}</p>
                </a>
            [/#list]
       [/#if]
    </div>
[/#if]
```

Thanks.

**================== Update ==================**

It seems to be a know bug as per https://jira.magnolia-cms.com/browse/MAGNOLIA-6245 but it is said to be fixed (in June 2015). However I still have the issue. See my comment in the Jira Ticket: https://jira.magnolia-cms.com/browse/MAGNOLIA-6245?focusedCommentId=120828&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-120828

**================== Update 2 ==================**

I setup a new 5.4.3 locally, where the issue does not occur. The issue still occurs at the 5.4.3 instance at my hosting provider though (about which my original posting is about). I downloaded the repo-conf, and made a diff with my local repo-conf folder, there are no differences in either jackrabbit-memory-search.xml nor jackrabbit-bundle-mysql-search.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem thanks to a hint in the Jira:
https://jira.magnolia-cms.com/browse/MAGNOLIA-6245?focusedCommentId=120872&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-120872

The lines

```
<!-- needed to highlight the searched term -->
<param name="supportHighlighting" value="true"/>
<!-- custom provider for getting an HTML excerpt in a query result with rep:excerpt() -->
<param name="excerptProviderClass" value="info.magnolia.jackrabbit.lucene.SearchHTMLExcerpt"/>
```

were also missing in the file

```
${magnolia.repositories.home}/magnolia/workspaces/website/workspace.xml
```

due to some mistake at the hosting provider's template which they use for setting up Magnolia.